# R - Create a vector containing unique URL Parameters existing in a data frame

Tags: r

From the following data frame `URLS`:

```
>dput(droplevels(head(URLS, 5)))

URLS <- structure(list(URLS = structure(c(3L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 2L), .Label = c("http://www.example.com/cms/en/product/channel.html?channel=db3a30433580b37101359f8ee6963814#Anker&ic=0590001", 
"http://www.example.com/cms/en/product/power/igbt/igbt-discrete/discrete-igbt-with-anti-parallel-diode/600v-and-1200v-trenchstop/channel.html?channel=db3a3043397219b6013977d62aa15462&ic=0590001", 
"http://www.example.com/cms/en/product/power/lighting-ics-and-audio-driver-ics/dc-dc-led-driver-ic-and-linear-control-solutions/CDM10V/productType.html?productType=5546d46253f65057015414dc7d576130&ic=0590001", 
"http://www.example.com/cms/en/product/promopages/pcim?ic=0590001", 
"http://www.example.com/dgdl/example-ApplicationNote_600V_TRENCHSTOP_Performance_IGBT.pdf-AN-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d46253f65057015452d6317a71df&ic=0590001"
), class = "factor")), .Names = "URLS", row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to create a vector `parameters` containing all unique URL parameters. In this dataframe, for instance, the output should be:

```
parameters <- c("channel","ic","productType","fileId")
```

My real data frame has more than 10000 observations. Therefore, doing it manually is not a viable option

Comment: What do you meant by parameters?

Comment: @akrun URL parameters are parts of the URL that passes additional information, normally to a server side script (PHP, ASP...). F.I. lot of sites uses the parameter `q` to send a search term to a script (www.example.com/search.html?q=foo)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try `urltools` package,

```
library(urltools)
url_parse(URLS$URLS)
```

To get just the parameter then,

```
url_parse(URLS$URLS)$parameter
#[1] "productType=5546d46253f65057015414dc7d576130&ic=0590001"
#[2] "channel=db3a30433580b37101359f8ee6963814"               
#[3] "ic=0590001"                                             
#[4] "fileId=5546d46253f65057015452d6317a71df&ic=0590001"     
#[5] "channel=db3a3043397219b6013977d62aa15462&ic=0590001"
```

or

```
pars <- parameters(URLS$URLS)
unique(sub('=.*', '', pars))
#[1] "productType" "channel"     "ic"          "fileId"
```

Comment: Yes, very handy. Gets all that regex out of the way

Comment: Thx for the answer. `urltools` is a great package for those who work a lot with URLs

Comment: Looks like `url_parse(URLS$URLS)$parameter` is the same as `parameters(URLS$URLS)`

Comment: ahh yes. Force of habbit, I always use it with `url_parse` as I find it faster to handle when having to do the same with domain or path etc.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `getFormParams()` from the *RCurl* package to get the named parameter values.  Then we just take the names.

```
params <- lapply(URLS$URLS, function(x) names(RCurl::getFormParams(x)))
unique(unlist(params))
# [1] "productType" "ic"          "channel"     "fileId"
```

Comment: Thx for your answer! However, I picked @Sotos answer as I already load `urltools` package in my script.

Comment: @agustin - No worries.  It's always nice to show alternative methods :)